# AngularFire Functions: Service functions is not available

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

`AppModule`:

```
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from "@angular/fire/app";
import { getFunctions, provideFunctions } from "@angular/fire/functions";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(getApp())),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

A component within a child module of AppModule:

```
import { Functions } from "@angular/fire/functions";

constructor(
    private functions: Functions,
  ) {}
```

Whenever this component initialized, my app crashes and I get the following error in the console:

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Service functions is not available
Error: Service functions is not available
    at Provider.getImmediate (index.esm2017.js:147:23)
    at getFunctions (index.esm2017.js:651:49)
    at angular-fire.js:227:48
    at angular-fire.js:160:59
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:25447:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (angular-fire.js:160:35)
    at angular-fire.js:227:21
    at app.module.ts:92:28
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25535:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:35)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:491:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:476:48)
```

What am I missing? Other AngularFire modules are working just fine, e.g. `Firestore`.

My dependencies:

```
"firebase": "9.8.0",
"@angular/fire": "7.3.0",
"@angular/core": "~13.3.1"
```

Update: I've been trying to fix this for quite a while. Suddenly functions started working, but then `@angular/fire/messaging` stopped. At one point I also had `@angular/fire/firestore` not working. It seems like there's always one of the providers that doesn't work, while all the others do, but it seems random which one it is. I'm running out of ideas..

Comment: Docs are out of date. but i took a peak at the source code, i think you need to inject FirebaseFunctions instead of just Functions

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen @angular/fire/functions does not export anything called FirebaseFunctions

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, I had another NPM package (beside Angular Fire) which installed "firebase" in a different (outdated) version.  As soon as I removed the other package, it worked